# How to display 0 if no record in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this query. Currently, this displays the **status_count** for the **logged users**. I want to update this query to display all the statuses from the **status** table and if the logged user has no record for any statuses to display **status_count as 0**.

```
$orderStatistics = OrderHeader::select('status.id', 'status.name', 'status.description', 'status.type', 'status.code',
                                                DB::raw('order_status,count(*) as status_count'))
                                        ->leftjoin('status', 'status.code', '=', 'order_header.order_status')
                                        ->orderBy('status.id')
                                        ->groupBy('order_status')
                                        ->where([['order_header.user_id', auth()->user()->id], ['status.type', 'ORD']])
                                        ->get();
```

Let's say the **status** table has one new record **TST** where **type** is equal to **ORD**. And **order_header** table does not contain any record for **TST** for the currently **logged user**.

**Current Response:**

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "note",
      "description": "note",
      "type": "ORD",
      "code": "NTE",
      "order_status": "NTE",
      "status_count": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "approved",
      "description": "approved",
      "type": "ORD",
      "code": "APR",
      "order_status": "APR",
      "status_count": 2
    },
]
```

**How I want is:**

```
    "data": [
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "note",
          "description": "note",
          "type": "ORD",
          "code": "NTE",
          "order_status": "NTE",
          "status_count": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "approved",
          "description": "approved",
          "type": "ORD",
          "code": "APR",
          "order_status": "APR",
          "status_count": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 13,
          "name": "test",
          "description": "test",
          "type": "ORD",
          "code": "TST",
          "order_status": "TST",
          "status_count": 0
        },

    ]
```

How to update my query to achieve this using **IFNULL**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `order_status,count(*)` is this a typo? should the comma be a dot?

Comment: No it's correct.

Comment: Left join will join all entries in `order_headers` with corresponding entries in `status` and then also keep all entries in `order_headers` with no corresponding `status` entry. I'm guessing you want the opposite so maybe try doing a `rightJoin` and grouping on `status.code` (though I'm sure there might be more nuances that just this)

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for the response. I guess my query above is wrong as I've written a condition to return only for the logged user. now I want is to display all the statuses from the status table with type ORD and display the count for the logged user, if no count display status_count as 0. it would be grateful if you could help me with this. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set up your model relations correctly, you should be able to do this by chaining:

```
withCount('status')
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: I have no model relations for this. Just I need to display all the statuses with type ORD from status table and if current logged user has no record for a status to display the status_count for it as 0.